# Is there a standard for storing time tracking data

Tags: xml, standards, time-tracking

Is there any kind of standard or common format for storing and exchanging time tracking data such as a common XML spec?

By time tracking data, I mean data that might be recorded in time keeping software such as dates, durations, projects, notes, etc.

Comment: Do you mean something like rfc 822? [Date & Time Formats on the Web](http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/).

Comment: That's a good start for specifics on formatting date and duration.  I'd like to find a broader format.  
Ideally I'd like to store data in a format that is most useful to third parties.<br/>
<br/>
For instance, is it more useful to be presented a date defined by<br/>
<br/>
W3C DTF<br/>
1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00<br/>
<br/>
or<br/>
SQL format<br/>
2008-09-03 13:39:16<br/>

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to refer to [HR-XML](http://www.hr-xml.org).

It's domain specific but time tracking in the human resource area may account for more than 50% of  use cases in business (Payroll, time management, time card, shift management, absence management, and so on).

Comment: Thanks. That's a very thorough, and possibly overly complex, standard.  It does seem to be in line with what I'm looking for.  The big question is how many organisations would actually be able to make use of data in that format.  Is it just a nice idea or something we actually see in the real world?